# C# sort rows of dataTable using interface

Tags: c#, sorting, interface, datatable

Here is my code for how I get data from a database and add it to a DataTable named data,
I have to sort this all table by data of row "Spelionu skaicius" using interface (increasingly), but I have no idea how to realize that, can someone help with that?
i know there is a lotof ways to sort this, but i have to make this using interface.

```
using (FbConnection fbBD = new FbConnection(csb.ToString()))
{
    fbBD.Open();
    FbTransaction transact = fbBD.BeginTransaction();
    FbCommand sqlReq =
        new FbCommand("SELECT vardas,pavarde,sp_skaicius,spelioniu_sk FROM zaidejai WHERE atspetas='Taip'", fbBD, transact);
    using (FbDataReader r = sqlReq.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (r.Read())
        {
            DataRow rw = dt.NewRow();
            rw["Vardas"] = r.GetString(0);
            rw["Pavarde"] = r.GetString(1);
            rw["Skaicius"] = r.GetValue(2);
            rw["Spelionu skaicius"] = r.GetValue(3);
            data.Rows.Add(rw);
        }
    }
    transact.Commit();
    fbBD.Close();
}
```

P.S. sorry for my English

Comment: Can't you just add ORDER BY spelioniu_sk ASC in your SQL query?  It looks like you're just getting the value of that field anyway, why not let the query do it for you?

Comment: What do you mean "By interface"?

Comment: using interface, for example IComperable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the datatable DefaultView property:

```
data.DefaultView.Sort = "Spelionu skaicius";
```

you can then work with data.DefaultView (a dataview) or if you need a datatable, you can do this:

```
data = data.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

**<-- EDIT -->**

The above is for regular sorting. If you want to use IComparable, you will have to use custom clases in stead of DataTable. [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727)'s an explanation of how.

Comment: First of all, I used data.DefaultView.Sort = "Spelionu skaicius";
it sorts from the bigest to smallest I need conversely.
Moreover, i was asked to sort this using interface

Comment: to invert the order, use "[Spelion uskaicius] DESC". Now, about the IComparable, why do you need this? do you really have a special rule for sorting?

Answer (score 1):

It's best if you let the database sort the data so instead, I would change your select to this:

```
    SELECT vardas,pavarde,sp_skaicius,spelioniu_sk 
    FROM zaidejai 
    WHERE atspetas='Taip'
    ORDER BY spelioniu_sk
```

Note that I used spelioniu_sk because that's the 4th column listed on your select which is then mapped to `Spelionu skaicius` in your datatable definition

If you still must sort the datatable after you've gotten the data from the database, perhaps in a different order, you can use the DataView propery of the DataTable as so:

```
data= data.DefaultView.Sort = "`Spelionu skaicius` ASC";
```

OR

```
data = data.DefaultView.Sort = "`Spelionu skaicius` DESC";
```

Depending on the order that you need to sort by.

Note: I am not sure whether the above Sort Expression will work fine. Since you have decided to name your column with a space in the middle, you may need to enclose the 2 words in either backquotes (as I did above) or maybe square brackets (eg `[Spelionu skaicius] ASC`)